# Run Tests not available in Force.com menu in force.com IDE

Tags: unit-test, eclipse, developer, force.com-ide

I installed a new version of Force.com IDE to (Eclipse Kepler for Java Developers) and switched to Force.com perspective. I do not see "run tests" as an option anymore.
[image]

I tried [this](https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000090lSIAQ) and it broke my Eclipse. Please let me know how I can fix this so I can run tests on my test classes in Eclipse. I know I can run tests in developer console as well but I want to have the option here as well.

Comment: try to restart once. or check vinod comment https://developer.salesforce.com/forums/?id=906F000000090lSIAQ

Comment: I don't even have the exact same line. My config.ini has different values. When I do his suggestion, my Eclipse won't even open. I think it doesn't work with my version of Eclipse (Kepler/Mars).

Comment: Currently I am working with Eclipse (Kepler) version with force.com v35 API. I have this option

Comment: I had the same version on my previous laptop and had the option. This new installation doesn't have it for some reason. Trying to figure out what that is.